# Upon clicking delete, rails refreshes page but does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a rails app for planning school assignments.

I have been experiencing a problem upon clicking the delete button on the web page it just refreshes the page but doesn't delete anything from the page.

Here is my destroy action from assignment_controller along with assignment_params.

```
def destroy 
    @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
    @assignment.destroy

    redirect_to assignments_path
end

private

def assignment_params
    params.require(:assignment).permit(:name)
end
```

And this is my index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing of Assignments</h1>

<% @assignment.each do |x| %>
    <h2><%= x.name %></h2>
    <%= link_to "Delete", assignments_path(@assignment),
        method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with the route but here is my routes.rb just in case.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users
resources :assignments

root 'home#index'

end
```

Thank you!

Comment: @goyalsachin52 thank you I will try that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", assignments_path(@assignment),
        method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", assignment_path(x),
        method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

You must pass the `x` not `@assignment` because you have been passed it in a loop. Also, change: `assignments_path` to `assignment_path`.

Comment: @chrishorton, if the answer helped you just vote it up. Thanks!

Comment: I would but I have to have a reputation first! @OJ1987

Comment: @chrishorton, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your link for delete to below

```
<%= link_to "Delete", x, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your feedback! this worked perfectly.